# how select in text only space have after word

Tags: javascript

I try to parse text in an array to use it in constructor functions or in variables

make it regular exprecions
`[A-Za-z0-9-_+,]+\s?`
but does the opposite select words that have space after

```js
let txt = "cart  monkey thing";
txt.replace(A-Za-z0-9-_+,]+\s?, "-");

console.log(txt);
//return "- --"
```

I thought you invest that expression but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to select space which comes after word as:

```
/(?<=\w+)\s+/g
```

```js
const regex = /(?<=\w+)\s+/g;
let txt = "cart  monkey thing";
txt = txt.replace(regex, "-");

console.log(txt);
```